# Trace not found in X-Ray Console AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-xray

I have tried multiple approaches but nothing seems to be working

Here's what I have done,

1. Created a Cloud9 Instance, initiated a maven application, added aws sdk java, x-ray core, x-ray instrumentor, x-ray sdk dependencies, Created DynamoDB Client ran the application, data inserted but error subsegment not found. Manually added segment, Error gone but no traces.
2. Create Spring Boot App, added same dependencies, added Xray servlet filter, added begin segment, begin subsegment, no error but no traces.

I have more approaches as well but these seems to be very close. Also I have not installed any agent or Daemon. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?

I am trying to create a simple java application, even a single page to insert data in DynamoDB and get the traces that's it.

Answer (score 1):

i don't have experience working on java sharing here Node JS example hope that will be helpful. tested this : https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-xray-sdk-node-sample

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
const XRayExpress = AWSXRay.express;
const express = require('express');

// Capture all AWS clients we create
const AWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));
AWS.config.update({region: process.env.DEFAULT_AWS_REGION || 'us-west-2'});

// Capture all outgoing https requests
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https'));
const https = require('https');

// Capture MySQL queries
const mysql = AWSXRay.captureMySQL(require('mysql'));

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(XRayExpress.openSegment('SampleSite'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const seg = AWSXRay.getSegment();
  const sub = seg.addNewSubsegment('customSubsegment');
  setTimeout(() => {
    sub.close();
    res.sendFile(`${process.cwd()}/index.html`);
  }, 500);
});

app.get('/aws-sdk/', (req, res) => {
  const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  const ddbPromise = ddb.listTables().promise();

  ddbPromise.then(function(data) {
    res.send(`ListTables result:\n ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.send(`Encountered error while calling ListTables: ${err}`);
  });
});

app.get('/http-request/', (req, res) => {
  const endpoint = 'https://amazon.com/';
  https.get(endpoint, (response) => {
    response.on('data', () => {});

    response.on('error', (err) => {
      res.send(`Encountered error while making HTTPS request: ${err}`);
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
      res.send(`Successfully reached ${endpoint}.`);
    });
  });
});

app.get('/mysql/', (req, res) => {
  const mysqlConfig = require('./mysql-config.json');
  const config = mysqlConfig.config;
  const table = mysqlConfig.table;

  if (!config.user || !config.database || !config.password || !config.host || !table) {
    res.send('Please correctly populate mysql-config.json');
    return;
  }

  const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
  connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`, (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(`Encountered error while querying ${table}: ${err}`);
      return;
    }
    res.send(`Retrieved the following results from ${table}:\n${results}`);
  });

  connection.end();
});

app.use(XRayExpress.closeSegment());

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```